# NodeJS date listener and then callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

Does anybody know a module, or a way to permit me to listen to the date and to make a specific action when the result of a comparison is true without using setTimeOut ?

What I need :

```
if(currentHour==="08:00:00"){
  doJob()
}
```

EDIT : to be more specific, what I exactly need is :

```
event.on((x==='toto'),function(){console.log('hi');}
```

Thanks for advance

Comment: Are you asking for the `new Date()` class?

Comment: I dont know, but I just need to make a job when the comparison is true, just like an event listener on this condition. What's new with Date class ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks you, but I didn't find what I need it this :-/. It's not specific to a date in fact. Just to make an event listener on a comparison.

Comment: So you're asking how to check the hour of the current date/time? Did you look at that class?

Comment: I look at that class. What I need is to make "event.on((x==='toto'),function(){console.log('hi');})

Comment: Then you just need to calculate how much time is left and call `setTimeout()`.

Comment: but you want to compare seconds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, you want to run a piece of code when it's time for it, i.e. you want to schedule an action?

If that's the case, you can easily use a module like node-schedule https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule to do this.

Have a look at the Date-based Scheduling section, it does what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

If this will be helpful you can use the taas library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/taas

```
var taas = require('taas');
taas.schedule(Date.now() + 5 * 1000 * 60, "http://example.com", "get", "a=6&b=7", function(error, response) {
    console.log(response.id);
    taas.cancel(response.id);
});
```