# Continuously check whether or not a date has been expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, web-applications

**Here's our scenario:**

We are using node w/ express for our web app and we need to create a background process that continuously checks the created date on multiple posts and when they expire. These expired dates are set by the user so the posts expire at different rates. When the date expires, our app should be triggering specific events.

We are considering using a "setInterval" but wasn't sure if this is the best long-term solution.

Is there a solution to have node continuously check whether or not a date has been expired? Upon expiring, the posts must trigger specific functions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909924/nodejs-date-listener-and-then-callback

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

1) use moment lib like this:

```
var date = moment("2013-03-24")
var now = moment();

if (now > date) {
   // date is past
} else {
   // date is future
}
```

2) use node-schedule like this:

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var futureDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000); // This is 24 hours from *now*

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(futureDate, function(){
  console.log('Do your work here.');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about your code but if u can catch the event when the users post, the easy way would be

```
setTimeout(whateverYouHaveTodo, expireTimeInMilliseconds);
```

each time an event is triggered.

And if you need to cancel the timeouts in the future, what i do personally is put the timeouts in a json object with the key as a unique id which you could identify the event specifically

Comment: Hi Leandro,

I appreciate your response but when I mentioned multiple posts, I was talking maybe 1000+ posts which make your solution not scalable in our opinion. I will edit my question.

Thanks!